# How to check the Spring Boot cache for a key and run cache put only if the key isn’t already present?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, caching, ehcache

Every time a user makes an API call we are looking to cache some user data so it’s not needed in each subsequent API call. So when user 1 makes a call, the data is cached and the method isn’t run (until the cache is evicted at a specified time). Now if user 2 makes a call the method will be run and that data added to the cache.

I know @CachePut can help me in running the method but how can I do a check to see if a value is already in the cache?

```
@Cacheable(value=“userRoles”)
public List<String> getRoles(String userId){
List<String> roles = someDao.getRoles(userId);
return roles;
}
```

Comment: 1) Show the method you mean. 2) Explain how this method knows about the users.

Comment: I can’t paste directly unfortunately but we can the user ID from the auth token I’m the request headers. Let me try to create something that’s close

Comment: Then provide some similar code, explain how it works now and how you want it to work.

Comment: Updated. So I want it to cache this method with a userId key and users list of roles as the value. If the user is present in the cache just fetch the values. If the user isn’t present, call the method

Comment: Now explain how it works currently. Like this: Step 1: Cache is empty. Step 2: getRoles(user1) is called. Value for user1 is cached. Step 3: getRoles(user1) is called. Method is not executed, value is found in cache and returned. Etc. Then explain what of these steps you want to work differently.

Comment: Can `putifAbsent` helpful? [Spring force @Cacheable to use putifAbsent instead of put](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29343980/spring-force-cacheable-to-use-putifabsent-instead-of-put)

Comment: @mentallurg yes on step 1-3 and then step 4) getRoles(user2) is called. Value for user2 is added to the cache. Step 5) getRoles(user2) is called. Method isn’t executed since it’s in the cache and returned. That’s basically all I am looking to do

Comment: @theq72: But cache **does already work** exactly as you described. When argument is called for the 1st time, the method is executed. It if is called for the 2nd time and the value is still in the cache, the method will not be executed and the value will be taken from the cache. I don't understand what do you want to change.

Comment: So that’s what I’m not getting, if I run the method and cache for user1 and later try it for user2 it checks to see if the value is present already and if it isn’t it runs the method? The documentation suggests @Cacheable is one once and only once so that’s where I am getting confused